# Actualizar combobox al volver el foco a form

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

Tengo el siguiente problema (les estaré agradecido por su ayuda): Tengo el siguiente `form`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`FormIngresoLibros` en el que ingreso información del libro en cuestión, al final tengo un `combobox` que se carga con datos de una BD en MySql, en caso que el autor no exista, al lado del combo se puede acceder a agregar al nuevo autor, pero cuando vuelvo el foco sobre el `form` original, el combo tiene info desactualizada, tengo que cerrar el `form` y volver a cargarlo (en el evento load del form tengo la carga de datos).

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que cuando ponga el foco de nuevo en el `form`, el combo se actualice sin tener que cerrar y volver a abrir.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? ¿En qué estas trabajando, windows forms, wpf, en qué? Vos lo que pretendes es que al momento de que el formulario entre en foco ejecutar un método que actualice el desplegable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un modo sencillo de solucionar tu problema, puede ser el uso del evento [Activated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activated?view=netframework-4.7.2) de `Form`.

Para implementarlo, simplemente deberías armar una función que actualice la información de tu `ComboBox`, y luego ejecutarla al momento de dispararse el evento [Activated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activated?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
//En el evento load del formulario
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Lo suscribo al evento Activated, haciendo que se ejecute la función ActualizarComboBox()
     this.Activated += (s, evt) => { ActualizarComboBox();  };
}

private void ActualizarComboBox()
{
     //Acá realizas la lógica de la función de actualización.
}
```

De esa manera, siempre que el formulario entre en foco, se ejecutará la función `ActualizarComboBox`

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió tu respuesta.